# redirect to a specific page in php by getting data from 3 dropdown lists

Tags: php, redirect

I want redirect to a specific page in php by getting data from 3(multiple) drop-down lists.

drop-down lists options contains the value from database.

Comment: i am uploading image but site dosn't allow me...

Comment: you can do it by passing values in array then array will be in URL as Parameter like: www.example.com/page.php?v1=1&v2=2 or store array in session then call session on next page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the values of your submitted form using `$_POST` and write a condition for decision making and redirect your page using header() function

Comment: you right but there are many values.... 8 values from one option 8 from other and 4 value from 3rd so total i have 20 values???

Comment: Yes you have 20 values but when you submit your page you'll get only 3 values each one from every dropdown

Comment: I have make a proces page which consists 'if statements' and my problem is solved thanks.....

Answer (score 1):

you can create redirection with javascript

```
<select name="abc" onchange="redirect(this.value)">
     <!-- your options here -->
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

function redirect(value){
    window.location.href = "http://www.yourdomain.com/"+value;
}
</script>
```

or you can try jquery.

```
<select name="abc" id="abc">
     <!-- your options here -->
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#abc").change(function(){
             window.location.href = $(this).val();
        });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: no i don't think any other option remain for client side redirection except javascript

Comment: you can use other javascript library if not efficient in javascript

Comment: also i have three select statements (three dropdown lists)

Comment: php is server side you can use 
if you are redirecting to external domain then exit( header("location:http://www.example.com/".$value) ); 

otherwise you can use
exit( header("location:/phpfile.php?".$value) );

Comment: if you want to use dropdown list then you have to submit form page then grab dopdown's value from $_POST/$_GET whatever you use to submit form then add to $value then use my previous code

Comment: i like this code [exit( header("location:/phpfile.php?".$value) );] and i have a submit button too...

Comment: ok then create a form page with dropdown list and submit form get value from $_GET/$_POST and use it as i told you in previous comment

Answer (score 1):

You can use j[Query change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/), as example:

```
<select class="target" id="drop1">
    <option value="URL_A">Option 1</option>
    <option value="URL_B">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select class="target" id="drop2">
    <option value="URL_C">Option 1</option>
    <option value="URL_D">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select class="target" id="drop3">
    <option value="URL_E">Option 1</option>
    <option value="URL_F">Option 2</option>
</select>

<script>
    $('.target').change(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        window.location = $("#" + id).val();
    });
</script>
```

I have also made example here http://jsfiddle.net/s2hLH/

Comment: i have three select statements. each have 8 , 8 and 4 option values